# Constructors or Static Methods for Loading and Saving Objects?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

I'm trying to decide whether it is better to use static methods for loading/saving objects, or use constructor/instance methods instead.

So, say for object `Project`, the instance version would be

```
public Project(path) { // Load project here }
public void Save(path) { // Save project here }
```

And the static version would be

```
public static Project Load(path) { // Load project and return result }
public static void Save(path, proj) { // Save project }
```

So, which do you prefer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither. Favor extracting persistence logic from your domain model and into a separate layer of classes.

(from a comment left in ChrisW's answer) Regarding the details of the domain object leaking into another class: you can restrict the visibility of those details, if your language permits, by using package-privacy/internal access. Alternatively, you can use a DTO approach.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no state to be maintained, only behavior, then use the static approach.  However, if the Project object needs to have state, then the constructor/instance method should be used.

Answer (score 1):

For the saving, I see no advantage to making `Save` a static method.

For the loading, defining a static `Load` method is better if `Project` is an abstract base class; but otherwise, defining and invoking a constructor is more idiomatic.

Altenatively I agree with moffdub's answer, if-and-only-if the functionality is big enough to make the persistence logic worth splitting/separating away into some other class. However, if you do this then the details of the data contained in `Project` are no longer private (and instead, these details must be shared with the class which loads and saves the Project instances).

Comment: The only real benefit of the static save is it can be moved to another class. I only really included it for completeness. But I agree that if the save is defined on the object it's probably worth using the instance version.

Comment: Regarding the details of the domain object leaking: you can restrict the visibility of those details, if your language permits, by using package-privacy/internal access. Alternatively, you can use a DTO approach.